# Rectangle shape drawable won't show as checkbox selector item

Tags: android, checkbox, shapes

I have defined a rectangle drawable like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="4dip"/>
    <solid android:color="#FF000000" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/service_checkbox_disabled_unchecked_stroke" />

</shape>
```

I can display the drawble as imageView without problems. However, it is supposed to be a drawble for one state of a checkbox. My selector for the checkbox button is defined like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_services_tick_unchecked_disabled" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_services_tick_unchecked_disabled" />

</selector>
```

And finally my checkbox:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb_tariff_3_next_month_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_services"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Can anyone tell, why does that not work? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please accept the answer below. This is unusually obscure bit of knowledge and deserves recognition. (I am not the poster).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You must add a size node to the shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <size android:width="30dp" android:height="30dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/blueBase"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/blueDark" />
</shape>
```

Comment: You save my day.

Comment: Make that two in one day! Was going nuts trying to figure out why it works fine with a file drawable but not an XML one.

Comment: This behavior seems very inconsistent to me. I manage to make it work by adding a transparent color as button and the selector as background. But my workaround didn't content me, how did you figure this out? What file did you look at? How do you know this, is in the docs?